# Arriving from Florida into JFK and waiting time to international flight over 10 hours.

Tags: airports, layovers, jfk

My niece is doing a birth rite trip to Israel. She flies into JFK in the early afternoon. Her connection isn't until 2 am.

Is it possible for me to meet her and wait with her so she isn't sitting in the airport for over ten hours alone?. Am I in a secure area the whole time?

Comment: You can't get into the secure area however she can come out of the secure area and meet you. You can even take a trip downtown together on the subway. 10 hours is an eternity.

Comment: @SheikPaul: That's an answer!

Comment: Thanks so much! How bad is it for her to go back through security? Or would she have to anyway?

Comment: *Very important.*  What airline(s) is she flying into and out of JFK?

Comment: Probably flying jet blue into JFK and El Al to Israel.

Answer (score 4):

While you would not be able to enter the secure area, your niece can join you outside of it in the concourse of any of the JFK terminals. Indeed, her flight from Florida may arrive in a different terminal from that of her onward flight to Israel, and she would need to make her way from the arrival terminal to the departure terminal.  In that case, she would have to go through security at the departure terminal.

Most trans-Atlantic airlines from JFK recommend arriving at the airport a minimum of 2 hours before flight departure and going through the check-in/security processes. At that time of the morning, 2 am, she should be able to go through security fairly expeditiously but, to be safe, she could use the [TSA online tool to view security wait times](https://apps.tsa.dhs.gov/mytsa/airport_search_results.aspx) at her departure terminal.

Comment: Thank you so much! So, she would have to re enter security in either case. I will share that link with her. Again, thank you!